# Семафоры и мьютексы в Linux

Tags: linux, семафоры

Необходимо наглядно продемонстрировать работу с семаформами и мьютексами в командной строке. Каким образом это возможно реализовать? Буду рад подробному примеру или коду (С / С++ / bash), который выполняет данное задание.

Comment: Язык какой-нибудь порекомендуйте, а то вдруг люди будут стараться , а вы скажете, что только в bash/Pascal/PHP ?

Comment: С / С++ / bash. Если можно, то с комментариями в коде. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: На shell, кстати, реализуется весьма просто, но надо глубже понимать систему.

Answer (score 0):

Параллельное программирование с блокировками вопрос очень большой, много книг и учебников. Могу выложить только самый простой пример, где задачи контролируются с помощью мютексов.

```
// > gcc -pthread mutex.c -o mutex
// > ./mutex
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char  mess[255] ;
pthread_mutex_t mutexTask;
pthread_mutex_t mutexConsole;

void * son(void * mes){

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexConsole);
  printf("Son get task: %s\n",mes);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexConsole);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexTask);
  // функция son заблокируется до получения права на собственную блокировку

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexConsole);
  printf("Son runs and read message=%s\n",mess);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexConsole);

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexTask);
  return NULL ;  }

int main(){

  int n ;
  pthread_t thrson;
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutexTask, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutexConsole, NULL);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexConsole);
  printf("Father makes task\n");
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexConsole);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexTask);
  // блокировка mutexTask чтобы никто не мешал работе

  pthread_create(&thrson,NULL, & son, "Wait!");
  // скоро параллельная нить начнёт свою работу

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexConsole);
  printf("Print message to son:");
  scanf("%s",&mess);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexConsole);

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexTask);
  // при освобождении mutexTask проснётся son
  sleep(5);

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexConsole);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexTask); }
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Был бы рад, если еще будут примеры демонстрации работы семафоров и мьютексов в командной строке.

Comment: @Maxim, можете посмотреть в [man sem_wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) и далее рекурсивно по SEE ALSO (начиная c  `sem_overview`). Если после прочтения тем возникнут конкретные вопросы, задавайте.